# intersection in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: geometry

i have this simple question :
is the intersection of $-x_1^2-x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=r^2$, $r\in\mathbb{R}$, with a plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is  a line in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

thanks for every answer

( i think if we take a plane $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0$ the intersection is not a line in $\mathbb{R}^4$)

Comment: With line do you mean straight line or more a curve? And you mean hyperplane ($3$D-plane in $4$D space), right?

Answer (score 0):

Your set is never empty. For instance, take $x_3=0$ and $x_4=\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+r^2}$, for any choice of $x_1$ and $x_2$. Your set is actually a surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: thanks edited, but is the intersection a line ?

Comment: No. It's a surface. I will add that to my answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: The intersection has codimension $1$ in the plane, isn't it? Unless the O.P. means a *hyperplane* in $\mathbf R^4$…

Comment: Given his example, I assumed that the OP meant hyperplane.